# A lambda function which is a member variable crashes

Tags: c++, c++11, random, lambda, functional-programming

The class `montecarlo` contains lambda as a member variable. This code can be compiled, but will cause "Segmentation fault(core dumped)" in run time. Could you explain how to fix it?

```
#include<random>
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

class montecarlo
{
  public:
    montecarlo(double x_min, double x_max);
    std::function<double()> rand;
};

montecarlo::montecarlo(double x_min, double x_max){
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt(rd());
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rand_(x_min, x_max); 
  rand = [&](){return rand_(mt);};
}

int main(){
  montecarlo x(0, 1);
  std::cout<<x.rand()<<std::endl;
}
```

And what made me wonder is when I change the constructor's implementation into the code below, it worked:

```
montecarlo::montecarlo(double x_min, double x_max){
  rand = [](){return 0;};
}
```

You would probably know, but let me say that what I want to do is not just using a random functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to capture `rand_` and `mt` by reference; they're local objects inside `montecarlo::montecarlo`, when lambda is called outside `montecarlo::montecarlo` these local objects have been destroyed and the references stored in lambda object have become dangled.

You could change it to capture by copy; and note you need to make the lambda `mutable` to make the invocation on `rand_` valid. e.g.

```
rand = [=]() mutable {return rand_(mt);};
```

Answer (score 5):

This is undefined behavior which should end with Segmentation Fault.
Note that your lambda captures everything by reference and life time variables it captures is limited to constructor processing. So when lambda is used it works on variables which do not exist anymore.

To fix it change lambda to capture variables by copy and it will work.

Or make this variables to be fields of the class.

Comment: "undefined behavior which should end with Segmentation Fault" is a non sequitur. By definition, undefined behaviour has **no restrictions** on what must or should or can happen.

Comment: I didn't meant that every UB leads to a crash (most of them don't), but this specific case should end with a crash.

Comment: "undefined behaviour which *in this case you observe* as SegFaulting"

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to copying the generator and distribution in the lambda is making them members of the class. Then they have the same lifetime as `rand`

```
class montecarlo
{
    std::mt19937 gen;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dis;
  public:
    montecarlo(double x_min, double x_max);
    std::function<double()> rand;
};

montecarlo::montecarlo(double x_min, double x_max)
  : gen(std::random_device()), 
    dis(x_min, x_max),
    rand([this](){ return dis(gen); })
{}
```

The name of this class suggests it will be doing other things. I don't recommend that you expand it, but instead split the generating off into it's own class.

```
class uniform_real_generator
{
    std::mt19937 gen;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dis;
  public:
    uniform_real_generator(double x_min, double x_max);
    double operator();
}

uniform_real_generator::uniform_real_generator(double x_min, double x_max)
  : gen(std::random_device()), 
    dis(x_min, x_max)
{}

double uniform_real_generator::operator()
{
    return dis(gen);
}

class montecarlo
{
    // other members
public:
    montecarlo(double x_min, double x_max/*, other args */);
    uniform_real_generator rand;
}

montecarlo::montecarlo(double x_min, double x_max/*, other args */)
  : rand(x_min, x_max) //, other member initialisers
{}
```